# Calling objects from dynamic UserControls VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Love these forums, I am a beginner when it comes to VB.NET and have run into some trouble.

Here is my Code snippet

```
    'decleare variables
    Dim vmcount As Integer
    Dim tabcount As Integer
    Dim userControl As Control
    Dim UserControlName As String

    vmcount = combo_vmcount.SelectedItem

    tabcount = 1

    tab_con_vm.TabPages.Clear()


    While (tabcount <= vmcount)

        Dim tabname As New TabPage

        'Load variables
        userControl = New calc_usercontrol_vm

        tabname.Text = "VM" & tabcount

        tabname.Name = "VM" & tabcount

        UserControlName = "UCVM" & tabcount

        userControl.Name = UserControlName

        'actions
        tab_con_vm.TabPages.Add(tabname)


        tabname.Controls.Add(userControl)

         'next
        tabcount = tabcount + 1


    End While
End Sub
```

The trouble I'm having is working out a way to be able to call the objects in the dynamically created usercontrols. I thought a list maybe an option but I am struggling to get the syntax/get it working. Wondering if anyone has some ideas or different approaches..

Thanks Guys
Richard

Comment: To what objects are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is most likely not the best way to solve the problem, I ended up creating an global array and build the user controls off that.

```
' USERCONTROL ARRAY
Public UCVMARRAY(30) As calc_usercontrol_vm






Dim tabcount As Integer

    Dim UCVMARRAYindex As Integer

    Dim userControl As Control 'control variable

    Dim UserControlName As String


    vmcount = combo_vmcount.SelectedItem

    tabcount = 1

    UCVMARRAYindex = 0

    tab_con_vm.TabPages.Clear()


    While (tabcount <= vmcount)

        Dim tabname As New TabPage ' Relook at this to improve the method used. Issue was that new page was not generated on loop.

        'Load variables

        userControl = New calc_usercontrol_vm
        ' loads UC

        tabname.Text = "VM" & tabcount

        tabname.Name = "VM" & tabcount

        UserControlName = "UCVM" & tabcount

        userControl.Name = UserControlName

        UCVMARRAY(UCVMARRAYindex) = userControl 'places it back 

        'actions
        tab_con_vm.TabPages.Add(tabname)

        tabname.Controls.Add(userControl)


        'next
        tabcount = tabcount + 1
        UCVMARRAYindex = UCVMARRAYindex + 1


    End While
End Sub
```

It's very basic but I got it working, the answers above are most likely a good solution but I my knowledge of vb.net were not up to scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of the tab you wish to work with

```
Dim calc_usercontrol As calc_usercontrol_vm = TabPages(index).userControl
```

Or if you don't know the index you can use the `IndexOfKey` method where the key is the `Name` of the tabcontrol

```
Dim index as Integer = TabPages.IndexOfKey("TabControlName")
```

Comment: +1, This is the correct way to do it (@msarchet, I thinked your idea, used the wrong code)

Comment: Thanks msarchet!

I'm still having some trouble getting this to work, sorry to be such a pain, could you elaborate on it a little more?

Comment: @RichardSims what do you need elaborating on?

Answer (score -1):

Call the [Page.LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) method and then add it to your page, preferrebly in the Init portion of the Page lifecycle.